# How to generate 100% Static website with Nuxt.js without API request?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am testing around with [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) to generate a static website.

Is it possible to generate a 100% static site when using an API to fetch data, so that one can get rid of the API and requests?

Based on my tests so far that all the files are generated properly and being hosted on the [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) and can be reached, except:

1. When hitting the pages directly via URL bar, no error (expected behavior)
2. When navigating to the pages via routes, the pages **is still sending the request to API** (does not exist outside local machine), even though the data has already been fetched and the `.html` file is generated with the data already during the generate process.

Using [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data) to get the data for the components from the API.

Comment: There was a discussion [100%static site possible?#1949](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1949) which comes down to: make requests during static generation (nuxt.config.js ... {generate:), save them to a json file, and then import that file either to vuex state or directly into components. 

I wonder if there is a ready solution for that, so that we don't have to write our own bicycles and miss edge cases, for Angular there is `TransferHttpCacheModule`...

Comment: before encountered that thread, that's exactly what I did, populate the vuex with the data during the generation process. Thank you for sharing this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use vuex (state management) and populate the state with the data during the generation process.

The state will be already populated in the generated `.html` file

For more information please refer to the this [thread](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1949) where it is being discussed.

**Example**:

```js
async fetch({ store }) {
  if (_.isEmpty(store.getters['tags/getTags'])) {
    await store.dispatch('tags/fetchTags');
  }
},
```

- The [fetch](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch#the-fetch-method) method is used to fill the store before rendering the page
- `fetchTags` is the actions making a request to api and populate the state
- The logic is quite simple: if the `tags` state is not already populated, then populate it by making a request to an api
- When running `nuxt generate` the state will be populated for the deployment, hence to api request won't be sent
- The state will be injected into the .html file (pic below for reference)

[image: state example populate in the .html file]

---

*If anyone have a better solution, please share, I will gladly accept that answer as a correct one :)*

Comment: Could you share at least some example code in the solution ? It's not very clear, do you save a state to a file and then read it, or it is magically works between route changes ?

Comment: have added the sample code on how I have done it.  State will be populated and saved into the .js file (let's call it nuxtjs magic). Then since a generated static website is still a Vue app everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to make your routes accessible via directly entering the url into the address bar if you are hosting your site in github pages. You just need to configure your webpack to generate multiple `index` files with the same `entry` point that will be stored in each `directory` based on your `routes`.

This is easily achieved if you are using [`vue-cli`](https://cli.vuejs.org/) to generate your project.

For example, I have these routes:

[image],

I just need to create a `vue.config.js` in the root of my project.

[image]

and inside the `vue.config.js` file, I just need to register several more [`pages`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) based on what's on my `router`.
Each `entry` point should be your `main.js` file, and the template should be your `index.html`.

The filename should be `<your-route>/index.html`

If you entered sub-directory into the `filename`, Vue will automatically create those directories if they don't exist during compilation. So if the filename you entered is `photography/index.html`, Vue will automatically create a `photography` directory inside the `dist` directory.

[image]

And if you check your `dist` directory, you will see the directories with an `index.html` inside.

[image]

So when you enter your route into the address bar, it will actually access one of these directories and display the `index.html`.

This is what I actually did to my homepage which I hosted in my [github](https://github.com/WisdomSky/wisdomsky.github.io/tree/develop) account.

**Here's my github page:** https://wisdomsky.github.io/

I have two pages the `about` and `photography` and if you will enter https://wisdomsky.github.io/photography into the address bar, it will render my photography page instead of receiving the Github 404 page.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, your answer is addressing point 1, which is working as expected :). If you inspect your photography page, you will still see that it is making a request api to unsplash (which might be the behavior you want), but for me the .html file with the data already generated so there is no point in trying to fetch that data from api again.

Comment: In Nuxt.JS you can determine if your page is served from `client` or from `server`. you can use that to wrap your API calls in a condition so that they won't be called again if your page is served via client. See https://nuxtjs.org/examples

Comment: @Julian Paolo Dayag, well, if requests won't be made on a client, then you will end up with empty content on routing, since it won't be requested. You either have to route between simple `.html` files without SPA routing, or cache requests at `nuxt generate` to a file, so that the client can't read data from that ready file and still have SPA routing.

Comment: my solution was to use vuex and populate the store manager during the generation process