# Pass payload for nuxtServerInit when generating pages

Tags: nuxt.js

How can I pass payload to nuxtInitServer when generating pages for a static site? Currently every page will send a request to nuxtInitServer (from store/index.js), but I'd like to pass this manullay as I can with page data: https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c10343

I have found: [How to generate 100% Static website with Nuxt.js without API request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815236/how-to-generate-100-static-website-with-nuxt-js-without-api-request) but that really doesn't answer my question. I tried implement something like that inside nuxtServerInit, but it seems as though the store is reset on each new page to generate.

I have also tried accessing `this` inside nuxt.config.js:generate:routes function, but that just returns the config settings.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `nuxtServerInit` is `context` - that object holds the `payload` data. You can check if payload is assigned and then populate nuxtServerInit as you like.

Alternatively you could implement some caching on axios calls to prevent your server from getting swamped.